# Change node during saving it

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using Drupal 7.34 and I have a problem..

My module is reacting on node changes. When a node is updated one or more other nodes are automatically being updated, too. I call a function that triggers that update in `hook_node_save`.

Everything is fine until I try to make changes to the node that was initially saved and is passed to the `hook_node_save`. The reason is actually pretty obviuos: The changes prepared during the inital save process are overwriting the changes made during the function that is called in `hook_node_save`.

So here is my question with an example: I want to change field_a of node 100 after node 100 is updated from somewhere around the system. How do I achieve that while having access to the initially updated values of node 100?

**Edit 1:**

My `hook_node_presave`:

```
if (!$node->is_new) {
  $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_oc_revision');
  if ($items) {
    _trigger_steps($items[0]['value'], $node);
  }
  debug($node);
}
```

The _trigger_steps() function changes the $node object passed by reference.

Now when I click save on a node form `hook_node_presave` is triggered twice. The first time the debug shows that the field is changed in the normal `$node` field, but not in the `$node->original` field. The second time the debug shows that the field is changed in the `$node->original` field, but not in the `$node` field.

Hope that gives more insight.

**Edit 2:**

One more thing to mention: When using the same code with manually calling `$node = node_load(100); node_save($node);` everything works like it should.

**Edit 3:**
This is the part of the code of the `_trigger_step` function that is executed.

```
$connected_node = user_activity_get_step_base_node($base_nid, $step['connected_node_type']); // In this special case this loads the node that was just updated

$items_base_field_name = field_get_items('node', $connected_node, $step['base_field_name']); // $step is a definition of a step to trigger.

$expert_uid = $process['coordinator_user'];

$expert_nid = $items_base_field_name[0]['target_id'];
$expert_nid = node_load($expert_nid) ? $expert_nid : '';
// check if expert uid is set and node is not already linked
if($expert_uid && !$expert_nid) {
  $expert_node = new stdClass;
  $expert_node->type = $step['node_type'];
  node_object_prepare($expert_node);

  $expert_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $expert_node->title = $node_type_names[$step['node_type']];
  $expert_node->uid = $expert_uid;
  $expert_node->promote = 0;
  // connect the nodes
  $expert_node->{$step['assignee_field_name']}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = $connected_node->nid;
  // tree assignment
  $expert_node->field_oc_revision[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $base_nid;
  $expert_node->field_oc_tree_element[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $step['sid'];

  // save new node
  node_save($expert_node);

  // if the updated node is the one that we want to change here, we just change the passed node. it is saved after hook_node_presave.
  if($updated_node) { // $updated_node is passed by reference
    $updated_node->{$step['base_field_name']}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = $expert_node->nid;
  // if not we set save it directly
  } else {
    $connected_node->{$step['base_field_name']}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = $expert_node->nid;
    node_save($connected_node); 
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!
cheers
j

Comment: if you explain it bit more it will be use full

Comment: We'd need to see what `_trigger_steps` is doing

Comment: Well.. this function is like 750 lines of code.. I will try to shrink it to what it really does.. One more thing to mention: When using the same code with manually calling `$node = node_load(100); node_save($node);` everything works like it should.

Comment: I added the code of the `_trigger_step` function

Comment: I found the problem in another module. It is solved now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long night of debugging I finally found the bug. I always thought that hook_node_presave is called twice when submitting a form. That is wrong. Took me a while to find out.

I then searched for `node_save` operations in my code through like 20 modules and found a module calling `node_save` in a custom node form submission handler. I removed it and it works now.

Thank you all for your help!